# Cannot ssh into a fresh install of CentOS minimal on lan

Tags: ssh, centos

I've downloaded [CentOS 7 Minimal](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/centos/7.0.1406/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-Minimal.iso) and installed on an old laptop. I want to be able to `ssh` to the machine from other machines on the same `lan`. But I keep getting this error ..

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.17 port 2110: No route to host
```

`192.168.0.17` .. Is the new `CentOS` machine.

```
rob@ciserver:~$ hostname
ciserver
```

`192.168.0.11` .. Is the machine I'm trying to access from.

```
rob@work:~$ ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | tail -1
          inet addr:192.168.0.11  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
rob@work:~$ ping -vvv 192.168.0.17
PING 192.168.0.17 (192.168.0.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.11 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

These are the config steps and info from my `CentOS` install, hopefully someone can help identify when I cannot remotely access the machine?

```
rob@ciserver:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp14s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
  link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
3: wlp20s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
  link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
  inet 192.168.0.17/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp20s0
    valid_lft 84703sec preferred_lft 84703sec
  inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/xx scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I modified my `ssh` config to listen on a different port and not allow `root` access ..

```
rob@ciserver:~$ grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Port 2110
rob@ciserver:~$ grep Root /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
PermitRootLogin no
rob@ciserver:~$ sudo systemctl reload sshd.service
rob@ciserver:~$ sudo service sshd restart
```

I added a new rule to firewall for updated `ssh` port ..

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=ssh
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2110/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
```

`/etc/hosts` contents ..

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain6
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain6
```

Comment: The next check: `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep ssh`. Also, can the other systems ping this server?

Comment: can you ping your router from ciserver ? e.g. ping 192.168.0.1 ?

Comment: @muru there is no output from `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep ssh`. `ciserver` cannot ping the router and other systems cannot ping `ciserver` either.

Comment: What is the IP address of the machine you are using to ssh to the new CentOS server? If it is a linux box try using ssh -vvv 192.168.0.17 and provide the output.

Comment: @Alfonso `192.168.0.11` is the IP of the source machine. I've updated question with results of `ssh -vvv` .. `From 192.168.0.11 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`

Comment: I believe you only showed the output of ping -vvv in your question instead of ssh -vvv

Comment: show `ip r` on both of the machines.

Comment: `No route to host` indicates a routing problem. Show `netstat -rn` from both machines.

Comment: If the `ciserver` can't even ping the router then the net connection to that machine is broken and no matter what you do on other machines nothing will work, you have to get a working net connection between `ciserver` and the router. I suggest using a cable instead of the `wlp20s0` interface (a wifi).

Comment: You should also considering disabling the firewall + selinux temporarily and see if you can connect to the server, in order to rule out networking issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think by default selinux is enabled and is only configured to allow port 22 for ssh. have you either disabled it or added an exception for the new port?

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2110
```

Comment: will never understand why people change ssh ports, security by obscurity does not work.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - you can often stop the probes by simply moving the port. Attacks follow economic theory. The majority of attackers don't perform a full port scan because its more expensive and risky than a simple port 22 probe. When they don't find anything on port 22, they will often move on to another victim. Ironically, bobbyrne01 and user164448 probably won't be a victim as often as you :) The economic theory also explains why phishing is so popular.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It doesn't protect against a targeted attack, but emperical evidence is pretty strong on the side of what jww says. Running on a different port will reduce probes by an astounding factor (at least a thousandfold).

Comment: I would never run an ssh port open to the Internet. As purely empirical tale, I once forgot to firewall an ssh entry when setting up an ISP, and in that single night, had 200k+ ssh probes.

Answer (score 1):

I am a necromancer, but if this should save some other poor soul the trouble:

In `nmcli` setup, I had applied the wrong subnet mask.

```
nmcli con add type ethernet con-name $CONNAME ifname $IFNAME \
    ip4 192.168.1.20 gw4 192.168.1.1
```

...gave me a mask of 255.255.255.255, with a `brd` (broadcast) equal to the server's IP. That server wasn't going to be talking to *anyone*.

The proper setup (this is minimal install, so it's important) would be

```
nmcli con add type ethernet con-name $CONNAME ifname $IFNAME \
    ip4 192.168.1.20/24 gw4 192.168.1.1
```

Of course, [check the CIDR prefix of your subnet mask](https://www.netgate.com/docs/pfsense/book/network/understanding-cidr-subnet-mask-notation.html) for your own network. But this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my fix in case it helps anyone else. I set the IP address using `nmtui` but never hit activate. The NIC stayed in DHCP mode so of course it didn't respond to pings.

Answer (score -2):

as root:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2110 -j ACCEPT
```

restart ssh service checks the ssh connection, or restart the system.

Comment: The question makes clear that OP added a firewall rule for this port...